# How to reference a system property within a user-defined .properties file?

Tags: java, properties, reference

I want to define a property for a working directory(say `work.dir=/home/username/working-directory`), for my production .properties file, without hard-coding the `/home/username`.

I want to reference the system property `user.home` in place on the hard-coded `/home/username`, to make `work.dir` more generic.

How do I reference the system property and concatenate it will other user-defined strings in a user-defined .properties?

**Note:** I don't want to access the user.home property in my java code, but from the .properties that I have defined. I want to be able to replace the value of the `work.dir` with different value for both my production and development(JUnit tests for example).

Answer (score 5):

Get the property from the file, then replace supported macros.

```
String propertyValue = System.getProperty("work.dir");
String userHome = System.getProperty("user.home" );
String evaluatedPropertyValue = propertyValue.replace("$user.home", userHome );
```

Answer (score 4):

You can manage your properties with [Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration//index.html) and use [Variable Interpolation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration//userguide/howto_basicfeatures.html#Variable_Interpolation)

> If you are familiar with Ant or Maven, you have most certainly already encountered the variables (like `${token}`) that are automatically expanded when the configuration file is loaded. Commons Configuration supports this feature as well[...]

That would allow a .properties file with

```
work.dir=${user.home}/working-directory
```

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not available in java.util.Properties. But many libraries add *variable substitution* to properties.

Here an example of what you are trying to do using [OWNER API](http://owner.aeonbits.org) library (see paragraph "importing properties"):

```
public interface SystemPropertiesExample extends Config {
    @DefaultValue("Welcome: ${user.name}")
    String welcomeString();

    @DefaultValue("${TMPDIR}/tempFile.tmp")
    File tempFile();
}

SystemPropertiesExample conf =
        ConfigFactory.create(SystemPropertiesExample.class, System.getProperties(), System.getenv());
String welcome = conf.welcomeString();
File temp = conf.tempFile();
```