# How to specify user.home in PropertyFile?

Tags: java, properties

I Have a application in which has a Variable 'file_Base_Path',and i'm reading its value from  propertyFile(say sample.properties). And i want to set the variable value to user.home and 
**${user.home}** is not working. How to set the value to user.home so that it works in both Linux and windows.

Note : i cant use System.getProperties('user.home') because the value is not always user.home it may vary

sample.properties:

```
    file_Base_Path=${user.home}
```

How i'm setting the value :

```
  properties.getProperty("file_Base_Path")  //i'm expecting '/home/user' but it is returning '${user.home}'
```

Thanks

Comment: I believe you don't need such a value in properties file. Wherever you need `/home/user` just use `System.getProperty("user.home")`

Comment: I thought `user.home` *did* work on Linux.

Comment: What do you mean by "the value is not always user.home"?

Comment: The value is not always '/home/user' if some other value '/home/root'(which is not user.home) is also allowed

Comment: `user.home` is the *name* of **logical** home directory for the user that the host system provides the `JVM` it is always `user.home` it will never be anything else and it represents what the host system say regardless of if it is `/home/user` or `/my/long/badly/named/home/dir` it is whatever represents the current users home directory.

Answer (score 0):

A properties-file does no environment variable substitutions...

The way to get environment variables is

```
System.getProperties("variablename");
```

If the `"variablename"` is variable in it self, why not configure that via the properties?

sample.properties:

```
userhome.variable.name=user.home
```

Java code:

```
String userhomeVariableName = properties.getProperty("userhome.variable.name");
String userhome = System.getProperties(userhomeVariableName);
```

Comment: I'm not expecting it to a user.home always

Answer (score 0):

why don't you do this:

```
 String localHome=properties.getProperty("file_Base_Path");
 if(localHome.equals("${user.home}"){
      localHome=System.getProperties("user.home");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Spring the `@Value` annotation will translate `${user.home}` to its appropriate value on injection.

Keep the sample.properties as is and in your class you would use:

```
@Value("${file_Base_Path}")
private String filePath;
```

And the `${user.home}` variable would be translated by Spring before being injected into the variable.

See [Value](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html) for more.

Alternatively use Apache Commons Configuration as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15157599/1145251)

If you don't want to use Spring or Apache Commons Configuration then you'd have to roll out your own solution as Properties and System.getProperties does no transformation on the content of a properties file. You would have to:

1. Check if the string contains "${" (for the cases when a user specifies a full path like "C:/temp" no transformation is necessary);
2. Extract the property content;
3. Use System.getProperty(String) to get the actual value;
4. Add the value back to the string in the position it was found (for the cases when you have something like `file_Base_Path=${user.home}/resources/${java.version}` for example).